# 「カンカン」という俗語あるいは方言

Tags: translation

小説を読んでいる途中、この意味不明な言葉が現れました：

> がらんとした部屋のまんなかには針の狂った**カンカン**が置かれ、床や壁は昼となく夜となくかつぎこまれるスクラップのためにまるでヤスリをかけたように毛ばったり…

次の段落にも：

> 刑事部長はそのカンカンの前に机を置き…

[日本三文オペラ　３１４頁](http://www.shinchosha.co.jp/book/112802/)（開高健著）

この「カンカン」を様々な辞書を引いてさがしてみたのですが、一般の辞書から、[zokugo-dict](http://search.zokugo-dict.com/search.cgi?charset=utf8&q=%E3%82%AB%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AB%E3%83%B3&s=%E8%BE%9E%E6%9B%B8%E5%86%85%E6%A4%9C%E7%B4%A2)からも、該当するものはありません。

小説のコンテクストから推測すれば、重量機を指している可能性がありますが、いかがですか。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

推測は当たっていますね。

[このページ](http://plaza.rakuten.co.jp/hirotkmt/diary/200912240000/)によると質量計は昔「貫貫{かんかん}」と呼ばれたそうです。

また、その他に看貫秤{かんかんばかり}というのもあります。
これは台貫{だいかん}の別の呼び方です。以下[ウィキペディア](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8F%B0%E8%B2%AB)からの抜粋です。

> 俗に「カンカン」と呼ばれ、これは重さを量ることあるいはそのために使用する台秤を意味する「看貫（かんかん）」という言葉に由来する。但し巷間では音韻から上記のゴング打鳴音（「カン！カン！」）を連想する人が多く、「（カンカンという）音が鳴るから、カンカンと呼ばれる」という説明も一般的に流布している。

まあ文章から察するとそんな大きいものではないので前者の貫貫の意味だと思います。